# How to extend the range of a wifi router using another router?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-networking

I dont want to buy a signal booster because on some occasions I would like to use the router independently too. But is it possible for 1 router to relay the wireless signals of another router ?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the wireless router.

If the wireless router can be configured to operate in ***repeater*** or *range expander* mode, then the answer is "yes".  However most (or maybe all) retail wireless routers do not have this mode; it is a mode offered in some access points (AP).

"Repeater" mode would be one of several configurations if the wireless router was modified by installing alternate firmware like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater).

> a Universal Wireless Repeater (is) a device that you can place anywhere and it will wirelessly repeat the strongest signal, onto another wireless network (with or without security). This functionality is also known as Wireless Client Bridge, or Range Expander. Unlike WDS, once you have this appliance setup, it will work with any open network.

And another mode

> in DD-WRT v24 is Repeater Bridge mode. This extends your primary LAN via secondary router (bridge router) and also allows wireless clients to connect to your secondary router. This extends the range of your wireless network while simultaneously allowing wired clients to connect to your secondary router.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Just configure the second router as a bridge.

Comment: both are not connected to each other neither they are connected to the same network. nothing common between them except that they are wifi.

Comment: If you need one to repeat the signal of the other, then they should be connected to each other in some way.